# Coercivity - Weak Poisson's equation

Tags: sobolev-spaces, poissons-equation, coercive

Given the weak formulation of the Poisson equation, i.e. For given source function $f\in H^{-1}(\Omega)$ find $u \in H_0^1(\Omega)$ such that
$$\int_{\Omega}\nabla u \cdot \nabla v \, dx= \int_{\Omega}fv \, dx \quad \text{for all } \,\,v\in H_0^1(\Omega).$$

To then apply Lax-Milgram one needs $a(u,v)=\int_{\Omega}\nabla u \cdot \nabla v \, dx$ to be coercive. So what I get is

$$a(u,u)=(\nabla u, \nabla u)_{L^2}=\Vert \nabla u \Vert_{L^2}^2=\vert u\vert_{1,2}^2$$
particularly $$a(u,u) \geq c \vert u\vert_{1,2}^2 $$
where $c=1$. Is the semi-norm sufficient or do I need to show it with regard to the norm $\Vert \cdot \Vert_{1,2}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I can just make use of the equivalence of the norms:
\begin{align}
\begin{split}
\vert u \vert_{1,2}  \leq \Vert u \Vert_{1,2} &=\Bigl ( \int_{\Omega} u^2 \, dx + \int_{\Omega} \nabla u \cdot \nabla u \, dx \Bigr )^{\frac{1}{2}} \\
& \leq \Bigl ( c \int_{\Omega} \nabla u \cdot \nabla u \, dx+  \int_{\Omega} \nabla u \cdot \nabla u \, dx \Bigr )^{\frac{1}{2}} \\
&=\Bigl ( (c+1)  \int_{\Omega} \nabla u \cdot \nabla u \, dx \Bigr )^{\frac{1}{2}} \\
&= \sqrt{c+1} \vert u \vert_{1,2},
\end{split}
\end{align}
where $c \in \mathbb R$ is the Poincare-constant.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the norm, but you can just use Poincaré's inequality (that in fact shows that the semi-norm is in this case an actual norm).